# Can a micro black hole hover above a regular black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, hawking-radiation

So let's say you have a black hole $A$, that is small enough for its gravity to be very small, but has strong hawking radiation, and larger black hole, $B$, with very small hawking radiation, but stronger gravity.

Can you choose masses, $A_m$ and $B_m$, and a distance between the black holes $p$, such that, due to the radiation pressure of $A$ on $B$, and the gravity of $B$ on $A$, the distance between them doesn't change (or stays inside a certain interval)?

Additionally, is there a configuration that is stable (resilient to small outside perturbations)?

NOTE: The black holes can't be touching. (In particular, $p \ne 0$.)

Comment: Why would there be a repulsive force? Isn't the Hawking radiation isotropic?

Comment: @Emil Only part of the hawking radiation will hit $B$.

Comment: Eddington luminosity?

Comment: Wouldn't the absorption of the radiation cause an attractive force instead?

Comment: @Horus Why would it attract? The radiation is imparting momentum to the $B$.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Sorry I got a little confused there.

Comment: A configuration that is stable would be one where p is large I suppose, though its probably not what you're looking for. Anything else though, I think would be very unstable, like balancing a pencil on its tip.

Comment: @Horus I was thinking that if they got closer, the radiation pressure would increase, balancing that out, and if they got farther, the opposite would happen.